# Vue reactivity with composition API clone props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-props

I have a component that is getting props from a parent. Now I really want to only clone the props - I don't want the changes to be reflected in the parent as well.

```
<template>
  <input-text v-model="form.name" />
</template>

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    record: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
      default: () => ({}),
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const form = ref({})

    // when props change, clone them
    watchEffect(() => {
      dForm.value = props.record
    })


    return { form }
  },
})
```

Now, I want to create a copy of the props each time they arrive - I don't want `v-model` to change the props in the parent - I only want the changes to happen locally, inside this component. How can I clone `props.record`? I tried `Object.assign({}, props.record)` and few other ways but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Deep Watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers)

```
const form = ref({})
watch(
   () => props.record,
   (newValue) => { Object.assign(form.value, newValue) },
   { deep: true } // <- deep watcher
)
```

> **Use with Caution**
>
> Deep watch requires traversing all nested properties in the watched
> object, and can be expensive when used on large data structures. Use
> it only when necessary and beware of the performance implications.

```js
const { createApp, ref, watch } = Vue
 
const Comp = {
  props: {
    record: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
      default: {},
    }
  },
  setup(props) {    
    const form = ref({})
    watch(
      () => props.record,
      (newValue) => { Object.assign(form.value, newValue) },
      { deep: true }
    )
    const add = () => { form.value.counter++ }
    return { form, add }
  },
  template: 'Comp: props.record: {{record}}<br/> form: {{form}} <button @click="add">+1</button> <br/>'  
} 
 
const App = {
  components: {
    Comp
  },
  setup() {
    const record = ref({
      counter: 0
    });    
    const add = () => { record.value.counter++ }
    return { record, add }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
record: {{record}} <button @click="add">+1</button> <br/>
<comp :record="record"></comp><br/>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```